# How to apply convolutional & pooling operation on an image

Tags: tensorflow, cnn

I am learning convolutional & pooling operation. I want to use them on the following image using tensorflow. This is an image of width=600, height=400 and 4 dimensional color channels.

[image: I want]

I want to use filter like `filter = np.array([[1, 0, -1], [2, 0, -2], [1, 0, -1]])`

Please help me.